# in _load dt = tstamp.to_pydatetime() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'

Tags: python

I was using backtrader to do some analysing work, but when I use bt.feeds to import csv sheet data, I met this error.
I also use "class PandasDataPlus(bt.feeds.PandasData)" to extend the lines of cerebro data, I still don't know where the error is.

```
import backtrader as bt
from backtrader.feeds import GenericCSVData
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
class PandasDataPlus(bt.feeds.PandasData):
lines = ('crossover','crossover2','below','below2', )
params = (('crossover', 7),('crossover2', 8),('below', 9),('below2', 10),)
class Stoch(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataclose = self.data.close
        self.order=None
        self.buyprice = None
        self.buycomm=None


    def next(self):
        print(self.datas[0].lines.getlinealiases())
        #print(self.data.lines.close[0])


    def notify_order(self, order):
        if order.status in [order.Submitted,order.Accepted]:
            return
        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            if order.isbuy():
                self.log(
                    'BUY EXECUTED, Price: %.2f,Cost: %.2f, Comm: %.2f' %
                    (order.executed.price,
                     order.executed.value,
                     order.executed.comm)
                )
                self.buyprice = order.executed.price
                self.buycomm = order.executed.comm
            else:
                self.log('SELL EXECUTED, Price:Price: %.2f,Cost: %.2f, Comm: %.2f' %
                         (order.executed.price,
                          order.executed.value,
                          order.executed.comm)
                         )
            self.bar_executed = len(self)
        elif order.status in [order.Canceled,order.Margin,order.Rejected]:
            self.log('Order Canceled/Margin/Rejected')
        self.order = None

    def notify_trader(self, order):
        if not trade.isclosed:
            return
        self.log('OPERATION PROFIT, GROSS %.2f , NET %.2f'%
                 (trade.pnl,trade.pnlcomm))
    def log(self,txt,dt=None,doprint=True):
        if doprint:
            dt=dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
            print('%s,%s,'% (dt.isoformat(), txt))


if __name__ == '__main__':
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
dataframe = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
df=dataframe
#df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns=['Date', 'time', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Datetime',inplace=True)
df['Stoch'] = pd.DataFrame(ta.stoch(df['High'],df['Low'],df['Close']),columns=['STOCHk_86_15_5'])
value = 89 
value2 = 20
df['crossover'] = ta.cross_value(df['Stoch'], value) 
df['below'] = ta.cross_value(df['Stoch'], 100-value,above=False)
df['crossover2'] = ta.cross_value(df['Stoch'], value2)
df['below2'] = ta.cross_value(df['Stoch'], 100-value2,above=False)
data_TSLA = PandasDataPlus(
    dataname=dataframe,
    fromdate=dt.datetime(2020,1,1),
    todate=dt.datetime(2021,1,1),
    timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Minutes,
    datetime = 0,
    open = 1,
    high = 2,
    low = 3,
    close = 4,
    volume = 5,
    openinterest = -1,
    crossover = 7,crossover2 = 8,below = 9,below2 = 10
    )
cerebro.adddata(data_TSLA)
cerebro.addstrategy(Stoch)
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.SharpeRatio,_name='sharpratio')
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.DrawDown, _name='drawdown')
cerebro.broker.setcash(10000.0)
cerebro.broker.setcommission(commission=0.0006)
cerebro.addsizer(bt.sizers.PercentSizer,percents=90)
result=cerebro.run()

print('Sharp:',result[0].analyzers.sharpratio.get_analysis()['sharperatio'])
print('Draw:',result[0].analyzers.drawdown.get_analysis()['max']['drawdown'])


cerebro.plot()
```

Here is my csv sheet data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVZlF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your post to fix code formatting (indentation).  For resolving your error, have you tried looking through the traceback output and at least determining the line number where the error occurs?  There is a lot going on in your code and we will not be able to help you without seeing your full traceback output, so you should include it in your post. Ideally, you should reduce the code to only the parts that produce the error and remove everything else, not dump the entire script into your post.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best answer, but here's my experience. I had the same problem in my code and the error was my index column 'date' was of type 'object' instead of the necessary 'datetime64[ns]'.
I ended up with this code:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=df.droplevel(level=0),
                                        name=ticker,
                                        plot=False)
```

I had to drop level=0 for the ticker column because I had 2 index values.